# Testing a conditional validation with remarkable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model with this validation:

```
  validates_numericality_of(:insert_oz,
                            :allow_blank=>true,
                            :greater_than=>0,
                            :if=>(proc do |note|
                                    !note.insert_pages.nil? &&
                                       note.insert_pages > 0
                                  end))
```

Using remarkable, how do I test a validation that uses the `:if` option?

If I do the obvious, and add the validation to my spec, changing "validates" to "should_validate":

```
  should_validate_numericality_of(:insert_oz,
                                  :allow_blank=>true,
                                  :greater_than=>0,
                                  :if=>(proc do |note|
                                          !note.insert_pages.nil? &&
                                            note.insert_pages > 0
                                        end))
```

Then the spec fails with this message:

```
'Processingnote should ensure numericality of insert oz is greater than 0 and allowing blank values' FAILED
Expected Processingnote to be invalid when insert oz is less than 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and catch statements?